# Node.js request starvation during large IO

Tags: json, node.js, csv

I have a node application that utilizes streams to read and process data from a DB.

I have a reader stream that makes a request via ZeroMQ and as it receives the data it pushes the data out to the next stream in the pipe.

The second stream will write the JSON data to a file and then pass the data on.

The final stream will convert the JSON data to a CSV and then write out a CSV file.

What I'm noticing is that when I'm receiving a "large" amount of data from the DB (over 10k rows and about 2MB of uncompressed raw data) that this process takes a considerable amount of time (~20 seconds). And during that 20 seconds, other requests are starved and can not complete.

Does this sound right? Is the there a way to relinquish the thread to allow it to do other work while the stream of data is being read/written? Or is there a better approach to handling this file I/O?

**EDIT FOR CODE**

```
function FirstStream(msg) {
  stream.Readable.call(this, { objectMode: true });
  this.request = msg;

  this._read = function() {
    var self = this;
    DBRequest.send(self.request).then(function(json) {
      json.Body.messages.forEach(function(item) {
        self.push(JSON.stringify(item));
      });
      self.push(null);
    });
  };
}
util.inherits(FirstStream, stream.Readable);

function SecondStream(filename, maxFileSize) {
  stream.Transform.call(this, { objectMode: true });

  this.filename = filename;
  this.jsonArray = [];
  this.buf = '';
  this.bufferTooBig = false;
  this.id = 0;
  this.maxFileSize = maxFileSize || MB;

  // Buffers JSON data, if the Buffer gets too large, then don't bother writing the JSON file
  this._write = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
    // If our buffer is too large, don't worry about caching more data
    if(!this.bufferTooBig) {
      var json = JSON.parse(chunk);
      this.jsonArray.push(json);
      this.buf = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(this.jsonArray));
      // If the filesize is going to be over our Max filesize, then forget about it
      if(this.buf.length > this.maxFileSize) {
        fs.unlink(filename, function(err) { });
        this.jsonArray = [];
        this.buf = '';
        this.bufferTooBig = true;
      }
    }
    // Pass the data on to the next stream
    this.push(chunk);
    done();
  };

  this._flush = function(done) {
    // If the filesize is within reason, then write out the file
    if(!this.bufferTooBig) {
      fs.writeFile(filename, this.buf.toString(), function(err) {
        if(err) {
          throw err;
        }
        done();
      });
    } else {
      done();
    }
  };
}
util.inherits(SecondStream, stream.Transform);

function ThirdStream(filename) {
  stream.Transform.call(this, { objectMode: true });

  this.fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

  this._write = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
    this.fileStream.write(csvMessage);
    this.push(csvMessage);
    done();
  };

  this._flush = function(done) {
    this.fileStream.end();
    done();
  };    
}
util.inherits(ThirdStream, stream.Transform);

// USE CASE
var backendStream = new FirstStream(request)
.pipe(new SecondStream(jsonFileName))
.pipe(new ThirdStream(csvFileName))
.on('finish', function() { /* write response back to client */ });
```

Comment: sounds to me like some of your code isn't asynchronous.

Comment: Show us your code.  If you're doing async IO, this shouldn't be a problem.  If it's synchronous IO, then that is the problem.